# "vertical-align: top" does not work for image + span content of table cell although all chilren elements are non-block

Tags: html, css

I need the `text` label to be in the top part of the table cell highlighted by a yellow background.

[image]

Although `vertical-align: top;` defined `td` selector and image element is `inline-block` (not `block`), the "text" in the bottom part of the table.

```css
.table {
  width: 200px;
  background: #FCF3CF;
}

.table td {
  vertical-align: top;
}


.image-defaultBackgroundUnderlay {
  
  display: inline-block;
  
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;

  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ececec;
  background: white;
}
  
.image-imageLayer {

  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;

  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="image-defaultBackgroundUnderlay">
        <div class="image-imageLayer" style="background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/960x540/626ffc/e6e6e6.png);"></div>
      </div>
      <span>text</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Please no wrapper solutions**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `veritcal-align:top` on the image and not the `td`

```css
.table {
  width: 200px;
  background: #FCF3CF;
}

.table td {
  /*vertical-align: top;*/
}

.image-defaultBackgroundUnderlay {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ececec;
  background: white;
  vertical-align:top
}

.image-imageLayer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="image-defaultBackgroundUnderlay">
        <div class="image-imageLayer" style="background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/960x540/626ffc/e6e6e6.png);"></div>
      </div>
      <span>text</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In your case the elements are already aligned to the top. To better understand here is an illustration:

```css
.table {
  width: 200px;
  background: #FCF3CF;
}

.table td {
  height: 150px;
}

.image-defaultBackgroundUnderlay {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ececec;
  background: white;
}

.image-imageLayer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
no alignement
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div style="border:2px solid red;">
        <div class="image-defaultBackgroundUnderlay">
          <div class="image-imageLayer" style="background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/960x540/626ffc/e6e6e6.png);"></div>
        </div>
        <span>text</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
aligned to top
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align:top;">
      <div style="border:2px solid red;">
        <div class="image-defaultBackgroundUnderlay">
          <div class="image-imageLayer" style="background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/960x540/626ffc/e6e6e6.png);"></div>
        </div>
        <span>text</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So `vertical-align` will align the whole line containing the image and text to the top and will not align all the elements to the top. The alignment of each element will depend of the `vertical-align` applied to them

Comment: I did not know these details! Thank you for the lesson!

Comment: @TakesiTokugawaYD don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your issue

Comment: Oh, I'm very sorry about forgot to accept your excellent answer because of the rush ...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `vertical-align: top`, you can align all inner items on top using `align-items: flex-start` on `flex` layout as follows.

```css
.table {
  width: 200px;
  background: #FCF3CF;
}

.table td {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}


.image-defaultBackgroundUnderlay {
  
  display: inline-block;
  
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;

  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ececec;
  background: white;
}
  
.image-imageLayer {

  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;

  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="image-defaultBackgroundUnderlay">
        <div class="image-imageLayer" style="background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/960x540/626ffc/e6e6e6.png);"></div>
      </div>
      <span>text</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. By why just `vertical-align: top;` does not work?

Comment: `vertical-align: top` is for `td`, not for all child elements. To make span to top, you can implement `vertical-align: top` on span tag too but instead of that, it's better to use flex-layout.